# I need help copying a file to all folders within a directory

Tags: batch-file

I need to be able to copy a file.txt in "C:\Some Directory\" to every folder within "C:\Some Other Directory"

So far, I have come up with this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Cd "C:\Some Other Directory"
for /d /r %%G in (*) do (
    Copy "C:\Some Directory\file.txt" "C:\Some Other Directory\%%G"
)
```

However, when I run it, It returns this error for each folder:

```
c:\Some Other Path\Folder
   0 file(s) copied
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Any ideas?

> ### Update

Derp, I just had to remove the /r, it was searching for files that didn't exist.

Comment: It obviously _doesn't_ return that error since `C:\Some Other Path` doesn't exist anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 2):

`%%G` will contain the entire destination path, so `"C:\Some Other Directory\%%G"` will be resolved to `"C:\Some Other Directory\C:\Some Other Directory\a_subdirectory"`

Simply remove the `C:\Some Other Directory\` prefix.